# How to get, mockable, currently logged in username for asp .net membership?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, asp.net-membership

Currently I am using `Membership.GetUser()` to get the currently logged in username. However this is a static method which is not Mockable. Is there any other way to get the currently logged in username that is mock friendly?

FYI: I am using Moq framework and NUnit.

Comment: Calling Membership.GetUser() just to get the username is way overkill, since that has to hit the database to return a full User object.  If you use the User property of the Controller or View base classes, then you can get the username from the IIdentity interface.

Comment: @MystereMan how reliable is the User property? in comparison to the Membership.GetUser()?

Comment: Well, since Membership.GetUser uses the same source to lookup the User, i'd say exactly as reliable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, in cases like this, you can create a wrapper interface which you can use to stub the GetUser() method.

```
public interface IMembersipService {
    MembershipUser GetUser();
}

public class MembersipService : IMembersipService
{
    public MembershipUser GetUser() {
        return Membership.GetUser();
    }
}
```

IMembersipService.GetUser() can be stub/mock based on your need.

Additional note: there are other routines in the [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.Security.Membership_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, which you may required to access. You can use the same interface to access wrap those methods. Having a wrapped interface like this around static members provide the testability.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC, `HttpContextBase` is designed to be mockable, so you can use its `User` property to get the current logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the logged in Username :

```
string userName = User.Identity.Name;
```